# Evaluating a member in an evaluated mathematical expression using python

Tags: python, evaluation

Here is my question:

Considering I have an input of this form (string input):

```
"(x = 5*y + 8) if z<3 else (x=4*y+9))"
```

I can evaluate this kind of string using this code:

```
import parser
formula = "(5*y + 8) if z<3 else (4*y+9)"
code = parser.expr(formula).compile()

y = 10
z=8
print eval(code)
```

However in this case, I don't have equalities in the member of the expression.

My question is: is there a simple way I parse the input to create some sort of mathematical expression, and then for example, just give y and z to finally compute the value of x; and also just give x and z to compute y?

If not, should I turn myself to abstract syntax trees and maybe recursive parsers and grammars? Or is there a library to do such?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic here, but you might want to look into `sympy`...

Comment: check [Xpresion](https://github.com/foo123/Xpresion) a simple expression parser engine for Python as well (ps i'm author)

Comment: nikos, have you an exemple using python?

Comment: yes, check the test folder in the repository, it has the same examples in js/.php and python, it supports user variables and user functions, but user defines the configuration (see examples), a default configuration is providded which use the ternary `? :` operator instead of python `if else`, but one can easily change this to pythonic syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rewrite the formula to be valid Python i.e. moving the assignment to `x` in front, then you could `compile()` and `exec` with a custom namespace dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function


def main():
    code = compile('x = (5*y + 8) if z<3 else (4*y+9)', '<main>', 'exec')
    namespace = {'y': 10, 'z': 8}
    exec code in namespace
    print(namespace['x'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With the `'exec'` argument the source code given to `compile()` can be anything that could be written in a module.

The `exec` command then executes the code with the given dictionary as namespace, i.e. all names used in the compiled code and not defined by the code itself are coming from this dictionary and all names the code (re)defines are also available from it.